# Exporting Data from Excel to SQL Server using VBA without loops

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and trying to find a way to export the data from a Excel 2016 sheet into SQL Server 2017, using VBA (without loops as we have large data in excel).

The excel data looks something like this.

```
Name     City      State Country
Person1  New York  NY    USA
Person2  Portland  OR    USA
Person3  Atlanta   GA    USA
```

etc..

The database table structure looks same as excel table

```
Name     City      State Country
Person1  New York  NY    USA
Person2  Portland  OR    USA
Person3  Atlanta   GA    USA
etc..
```

Any response with some sample code will be a great help. Thank you

Comment: Would help to briefly cover what other solutions you've tried and what problems you had implementing them.